# Changing index type from a value_counts()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to change the index type from `int` to `string` after a `value_counts()`

```
df
['value']
.value_counts()
.sort_index()
```

output:

```
40.0      1448
45.0     28558
50.0     83675
55.0     96377
60.0     47351
65.0     13226
70.0      2602
75.0       568
80.0        72
100.0       52
105.0       53
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

expected output:

```
40.0      1448
45.0     28558
50.0     83675
55.0     96377
60.0     47351
65.0     13226
70.0      2602
75.0       568
80.0        72
100.0       52
105.0       53
Name: value, dtype: string
```

Comment: why not adding  `.astype(str)`
 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need convert sorted index values like `40.0` use `rename`:

```
df['value'].value_counts().sort_index().rename(index=str)
```

If need convert count values like `1448` use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['value'].value_counts().sort_index().astype(str)
```